# How do you load a screen from an external .js file?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My goal is to render my homescreen from an external .js file called home.js. This .js file is located in a directory below root project directory in a a folder called "screens". I am having trouble rendering the contents in that home.js file. If I move the code from my home.js file back into the app.js file it works perfectly fine. I am trying to take a modular approach since this is best practice and would rather not stuff everything into the app.js file. I plan on creating more screens in the near future but am trying to wrap my mind around the basics first.

My current code in the app.js file

```
// In App.js in a new project

import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import HomeScreen from './screens/home.js';


/*
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
*/

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    //Details: DetailsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
```

The code in my home.js file is

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit 1: 
My current error is

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router')

createNavigationContainer
    C:\Repos\demoProject\node_modules@react-navigation\native\src\createAppContainer.js:88:30
<unknown>
    C:\Repos\demoProject\App.js:24:34
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Repos\demoProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    C:\Repos\demoProject\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:4
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Repos\demoProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    C:\Repos\demoProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:197:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0
```

Comment: Are you exporting `HomeScreen` component?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I have just made the changes that adam roberts suggested since I was not exporting it. But I am still getting the same error message

Comment: Post full error stack here.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I added it into my original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not exporting your HomeScreen component, you can do this by adding an `export default` infront of the class definition, or underneath.

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Or

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen
```

You're also attempting to export AppNavigator before it is instantiated. You need to move the export below.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    //Details: DetailsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: I just replaced that homescreen class in my home.js file and i'm still getting the same error message as before. I tried restarting the instance as well both times with no luck. I am emulating to a physical IPhone SE device using the Expo app.

Comment: I just replicated your error and build (I'm guessing you're following the react-navigation guide). Your problem is in the order within app.js - you're attempting to export AppNavigator before it is instantiated, you need to move the export underneath. I've updated my answer.

Comment: lol I am trying to follow that guide and have successfully created their code successfully in my project. I just wanted to break into separate files than how they illustrate in that guide for the sake of understanding the connectivity of things and their purpose. I am new to react and app development so I was expecting navigation to be as easy as it is on the web with <a href> but I guess that would have been too easy.....

Comment: React navigation isn't the easiest library to get your head around. If you're using expo it can help to setup a fully managed project and take a look at the way they use react-navigation (it's already split into separate files with stacks set up etc.) - it's a great way to get your head around the library's ins and outs. Did that last change clear the error?

Comment: Ya. That last change in my app.js file fixed it. I should have looked at that realized I was calling on something that wasn't even initiated yet. I got a lot more playing around I gotta do before I even try to set up something basic with this because the export/import part is confusing me especially with the "default" option tacked onto it. Anyways, thank you for your help!